# Heisenberg group is simply connected?

Tags: lie-groups, fundamental-groups

I have a question regarding the Heisenberg group. I understand that this group is simply related. In the matrix case, the argument to verify this is the following.

The application $(a,b,c)\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & a & b\\ 0&1&c\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix},\, a,\, b,\, c\in\mathbb{R}$ is a homeomorphism.Therefore the Heisenberg group is simply connected because $\mathbb{R}^3$ is simply connected.

Question 1. The set $H=\left\{\mathrm{e}^{a\partial_x+bx+cI}:a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$ is the
Heisenberg group? (with operators)

Similarly to the matrix case.\

Question 2. The application $(a,b,c)\mapsto \mathrm{e}^{a\partial_x+bx+cI}$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes (you mean "homeomorphism").

Comment: thanks. Do you know any reference where I can find the Heisenberg group but as operators? I only find it in its matrix version

Comment: It is briefly alluded to here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Heisenberg_algebra